# How to stop json object keys names losing it's doublequotes?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, key-value

I have this function in my NodeJs application.

```js
var createChatUser = function(payloadData, callback) {

    console.log(payloadData);
    var user = {
        "username": payloadData.username,
        "password": payloadData.password
    };
    console.log(user);
    Service.ChatService.createUser(user, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here I am getting payload data which contains the username and password.
and I am storing this username and password in another object user which have keys names "username" and "password" in double quotes. But when I print this user on the console I am not getting these keys in double quotes.

```
{ username: 'testUser', password: 'testUser@123' }
```

so, my question is what should I do to keep these double quotes in keys names.
I have to store this object in openfire which is not accepting it because of an unsupported format. so how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keys of an object are almost always string. When you log in console, every browser has its own way of representing values. This does not mean your object is mutated. So you should not worry about quotes when you see in console. Its just a way to make your logs more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the difference between an object and its representation. It sounds like the payload you receive is either an object, or a JSON string you're parsing into an object. When you log the object to the console, how it's represented in the console depends on the console.

> I have to store this object in openfire which is not accepting it because of an unsupported format. so how?

It sounds like openfire wants you to send it JSON. If so, you create a JSON string from an object via `JSON.stringify`:

```
Service.ChatService.createUser(JSON.stringify(user), function(err, data) {
// ----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----^
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
var user1 = {
"\"username\"": "Taksu",
"\"Password\"": "wtf"
};
console.log(user1);
```

If you need backslash characters you can add them using "\". You can read more about escape sequence [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes).

I hope that helps!!